# Custom ListView - cannot instantiate the type ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvResult);
   ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(Prueba.this, imageList, list1, list2);
   lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

And it gives an Error:
`Cannot instantiate the type ListAdapter`

In the same package, I have created a class called `ListAdapter.java` with its code.
I don't know what that error means.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ListAdapter is also a class in the android.widget package. It is possible that you are importing this, and this is trying to be instantiated rather than your local ListAdapter class.

Your options are:

1. Try renaming your ListAdapter class to something different, to remove the possible conflict.
2. Remove `import android.widget.ListAdapter;` or `import android.widget.*;` from your code.
3. fully qualify the class that you want to use (i.e. `com.mycompany.ListAdapter`)

Comment: Yes, i have renamed the class, and everything alright. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

See [Custom Listview](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296).